# cannot read cookie after setting it

Tags: perl, cookies

When I try to get into the "if cookie exists then redirect" function it doesn't enter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/srv/www/abc/m/www

require "api";

my $db = db();

use CGI;
use DBI;

use strict;
use warnings;

#use CGI qw( :standard -nph );

# read the CGI params
my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $cookie = $cgi->param("loggedin");
#my $cookie = $cgi->cookie("loggedin");

if ( $cookie ) {
    print $cgi->redirect("http://host.com");
    exit;
}

...

if ( $userID ) {
    $cgi->cookie( -name => 'loggedin', -value => '1' ,-expires => '+4h', -path => '/' );
    print $cgi->redirect("http://host.com");
    exit;
}
```

#### UPDATE

I'd like to determine whether the cookie that I set at the bottom of the page is present, and if so then perform a redirect. This code is within the `if ( $cookie )` block.

Comment: You are mixing some stuff up. Cookies are not CGI params.

Comment: @simbabque ok then can you assist in an implementation?

Comment: If you explain what you want to do, sure.

Comment: @simbabque explained

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#HTTP-COOKIES) to learn how to *set* and *get* cookies. Basically:

- With `-value`, a cookie is created. It must be passed to `header` or `redirect` to actually set it.
- Without `-value`, the values of the cookie is returned.

**Setting a cookie:**

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name    => 'loggedin',
                           -value   => '1',
                           -expires => '+4h',
                           -path    => '/' );
print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
```

**Retrieving a cookie:**

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('loggedin');  # Short for: $cgi->cookie( -name=>'loggedin' )
if ($cookie) {
    # cookie "loggedin" was set
}
```

**Setting a cookie and redirecting:**

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name    => 'loggedin',
                           -value   => '1',
                           -expires => '+4h',
                           -path    => '/' );
print $cgi->redirect(
    -uri    => 'http://host.com',
    -status => 302,
    -cookie => $cookie
);
```

**Deleting a cookie and redirecting:**

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name    => 'loggedin',
                           -value   => '',
                           -expires => '-1d' );
print $cgi->redirect(
    -uri    => 'http://host.com',
    -status => 302,
    -cookie => $cookie
);
```

Please note that setting cookies and redirecting at the same time is browser and/or webserver dependent.

Comment: According to the [SYNOPSIS in CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#SYNOPSIS) the commented out code `$cgi->cookie("loggedin")` should have worked too.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, but I guess the setting of the cookie didn't. It's not sufficient to call `$cgi->cookie(…)`, you also need to add that to the header so it actually gets sent to the server.

Comment: That's true. Didn't notice that part in the question. Happily, it's been a while since I used CGI.pm :)

Comment: @simbabque I still have a page running with CGI and was a bit disappointed that it's no longer a core module. However, my page works properly and I didn't have the time yet to switch to the new template things everybody talks about. ;-)

Comment: I've probably linked you this before, but you should watch it again. [Sawyer X explaining why _CGI.pm must die_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s) at our German Perl Workshop in Hannover in 2014. Also, come to the next one in Hamburg!